# Passing two arrays as parameters and calculating the sum of them in c++

Tags: c++

Write a function which will take two arrays as parameters and add the individual
elements of each array together such that firstArray[i] = firstArray[i] +
secondArray[i] where 0 <= i <= 4.

```
int[] sumEqualLengthArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] result = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    return result;
}
```

I have been stuck on this for a while now and I just can't get my head around what the answer is. I have attempted to answer it in the code above. I am a beginner to C++ programming as I am studying it in my free time. An answer to this question would really help!

Comment: Can you use `vector` in your assignment?

Comment: it's not an assignment, so I can use what I want.

Comment: Where did you get the `a.length` syntax from? Also you are not doing `firstArray[i] = firstArray[i] + secondArray[i]`.

Comment: So use `std::vector`

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I was unable to implement firstArray[i] = firstArray[i] + secondArray[i]

Comment: use `std::vector` and algorithms (i guess it is `std::transform` but without warranty, i never remember which one is for what)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you said you can use *anything*, Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [`std::plus<int>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus_void). something like this :

```
std::transform (a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), a.begin(), std::plus<int>());
```

If you insist on using normal arrays (here assume `a` and `b` are arrays) then you can do something like this :

```
std::transform(a, &a[number_of_elements], b, a, std::plus<int>());
```

But please, don't.. Use `std::vector`.

**How to use first approach :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> b = {1, 2, 3};
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), a.begin(), std::plus<int>());
    for(auto iter = a.begin(); iter != a.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**How to use second approach :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int b[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    std::transform(a, &a[0] + 3, b, a, std::plus<int>());
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jt8146 why not?

Comment: I would like to explore alternative methods? As I have only just started.. The exercise I am doing there has been no mention of vector.

Comment: would I simply use std::transform(a, &a[number_of_elements + 1], b, a, std::plus<int>()); or do  need to add more in order to make it print the output etc. In other words, how do I incorporate this in order to get the final answer

Comment: How exactly is it implementing this: firstArray[i] = firstArray[i] + secondArray[i] where 0 <= i <= 4. @Hamed

Comment: Also, I get an error: namespace "std" has no member "transform" and it also states that identifier a is undefined.

Comment: well the question states to add the individual elements of each array together such that firstArray[i] = firstArray[i] + secondArray[i] where 0 <= i <= 4. It's just hard to grasp that std: :transform is just the answer.

Comment: Sinces adding #include <algorithm>  I have 2 errors:                                        1. <error-type> std::transform                                                                                     2. no instance of overloaded function "std:transform" matches the specified type

Comment: How would I go about implementing it myself?

Comment: Using the 2nd approach I have "return value type does not match the function type" error

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
std::vector<int> sumEqualLengthArrays(const std::vector& rhs, 
                                      const std::vector& lhs){
  if(lhs.length() == rhs.length()){
    std::vector<int> result(rhs.length(), 0);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rhs.length; ++i){
      result[i] = rhs[i] + lhs[i];
    }
    return result;
  }else{
    std::cout << "Length is not equal!" << std::endl;
    return rhs;
  }
}
```

I would advise to use vectors instead of arrays and check the length before usage just in case to avoid errors.

Comment: std::vector has no `length` member. Did you mean `size` ?

Answer (score 0):

You've written the summing expression already in the problem formulation. If you look at it once again, you'll see that the result is stored in `first` and there's no need in separate `result` array (returning an array is not a trivial thing in C++).

And, speaking of which, passing arrays as arguments is not easy either.

Assuming, you don't use `std::vector`, simple options are as follows.

1. `int a[]` (note the position of square brackets) as a function formal argument is synonymous to a pointer. It does not contain any size information, so you'll have to add a third argument which is the minimal size of both arrays:

`int *add(int a[], int b[], std::size_t commonSize) { // commonSize is the least of a's and b's sizes
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < commonSize; ++i) a[i] += b[i];
    return a;
}`

2. You can deduce array's size when passed by reference, this is allowed in C++ and is a serious deviation from classic C:

`template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B> int (&add(int (&a)[A], int (&b)[B]))[A] {
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < std::min(A, B); ++i) a[i] += b[i];
    return a;
}`

Then the common size is the minimum of `A` and `B`.

3. You can use `std::array`, this is almost the same as previous option

`template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B> void add(std::array<int, A> &a, std::array<int, B> const &b);`

This way you can even use range-for loops, or, for instance, STL algorithms (which tend to acquire parallelized and non-sequential overloads recently), though it requires a small amount of additional work (which is a bit too large to fit in this margin).

Comment: "returning an array is not a trivial thing in C++" what is this supposed to mean? Returning a c-array is just impossible while returning a `std::array`/`std::vector` is as trivial as it can get

Comment: Suppose I wish to use the first example.. where would I position the code in my program? Also, how would I print out the answer?

Comment: @Jt8146 It is a function you put anywhere in the top-level namespace and call from `main()` (or wherever). The answer would be stored in `a`, the first argument of your call.

Comment: @user463035818 Returning an `std::array` makes you totally dependent on RVO (otherwise make yourself ready for the O(N) `return` statement). You cannot return a C array by value, only by reference, provided you know its size at compile-time, so the familiar Java syntax does not work here. `std::vector` is out of question's scope at all (yes, it is generally advised to use `vector`s instead of arrays, but it is even more advised to realize all the implications of any general advice). Sorry, that all taken, does not look quite trivial for a beginner to me.